# Adding tax total based on tax name for each type of tax

Tags: jquery

I have created a invoice page like below format

```
Item name desc discount unitprice tax1 tax2 price
```

At below there is

```
 subTotal   540
   Vat @5%  550
   Tax2@12% 430
   Tax3@13% 543
    ....
    total
```

Here each item have maximum two taxes I want to display
tax based on tax name and for each item then finally sum of all taxes total

**For tax 1 I'm using:**

```
<span id="item_tax1">
   <input type="text" name="tax1name" value="VAT" class="tax1name tax input-mini"/> 
   <input type="hidden" name="tax1value" value="5" class="tax1value input-mini"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="tax1"  value="44" class="tax1 input-mini"/> 
</span>
```

**For tax 2 I'm using:**

```
<span id="item_tax2">
   <input type="text" name="tax1name" value="Service" class="tax2name tax input-mini"/> 
   <input type="hidden" name="tax2value" value="4" cssClass="tax2value input-mini"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="tax2"  value="45" class="tax2 input-mini"/> 
</span>
```

I am calculating tax for tax 1 and tax 2 and storing it to `<input type="hidden" name="tax1" class="tax1 input-mini"/>` and for tax 2 at `class="tax2"`

Now I want to add all taxes price according to tax name as shown above.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Let me understand.. Do you want to calculate the **total** of the taxes? Or you want to make a list of all the taxes and their value?If no, please clarify it more..

Comment: Yes total of taxex based on tax name like For VAT it should show all VAT sume stored in `.tax1` or at `.tax2`

Comment: How do we know that `.tax1` and `.tax2` related to VAT (or any other tax)? Do you add a class to the `hiddens` with the expression `vat`?

Comment: inside `<span id="item_tax2">` or `<span id="item_tax1"> `<s:textfield name="tax1name" value="%{tax2name}" cssClass="tax2name tax input-mini"/>`` shows tax name like VAT OR sonme thing else similar for  `<s:textfield name="tax1name" value="%{tax1name}" cssClass="tax1name tax input-mini"/>`

Comment: Maybe, to better understanding, please replace the code snippets to an html snippets (the result not the server code). I think that if I will see the actual result I could help..

Comment: based on `.tax1name'  and tax2name' if name is same then I have to show sum of `tax1` and /or `tax2` value that is inside table  with specified invoice format as above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101249/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-xrcwrn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var taxes = {},
    total = 0;

$('.tax').each(function(){
  var elm = $(this),
      name = elm.val(),
      amount = elm.next().val();

  if (!taxes[name]) {
    taxes[name] = 0;
  }
  taxes[name] += parseFloat(amount);
  total += parseFloat(amount)
});

for (var tax in taxes) {
  $('<div />').html(tax + ': ' + taxes[tax]).appendTo('#result');
}

$('#result').append('total: ' + total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      VAT1
    </td>
    <td>
      VAT2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="tax1name" value="VAT" class="tax1name tax input-mini"/> 
      <input type="text" name="VAT1" value="10" cssClass="tax1value input-mini"/> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="tax2name" value="serviceTax" class="tax1name tax input-mini"/> 
      <input type="text" name="VAT2" value="23" cssClass="tax2value input-mini"/> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="tax1name" value="education" class="tax1name tax input-mini"/> 
      <input type="text" name="VAT1" value="42" cssClass="tax1value input-mini"/> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="tax2name" value="VAT" class="tax1name tax input-mini"/> 
      <input type="text" name="VAT2" value="55" cssClass="tax2value input-mini"/> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="tax1name" value="serviceTax" class="tax1name tax input-mini"/> 
      <input type="text" name="VAT1" value="68" cssClass="tax1value input-mini"/> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="tax2name" value="education" class="tax1name tax input-mini"/> 
      <input type="text" name="VAT2" value="66" cssClass="tax2value input-mini"/> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="result"></div>
```